# Is that possible to use a string as a name in opencv FileStorage

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to write an XML file using opencv FileStorage object.

Most of the examples I get to see works like the  following

```
FileStorage fs("d:\\1.xml" , FileStorage::WRITE); 
fs << "one" << 1;
```

I'd like to write  a section with modified name variable , which means that the text would not have to be inserted in compile time. I look for something like this:

```
 string st = "1"; 
 fs << st.c_str() << 1;
```

However I keep on getting run time error. it's refused to work, I have tried using opencv string type, stl string type , char*, but still can't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one. Looking in `persistence.cpp` I have found that the error is thrown because   `cv_isalpha` is checked on the variable name. This means that your variable name should be beginning with a letter!

Try doing the following:

```
int main() {
    string oName; 
    oName = "a"; // Now, THIS will crash if you assign "number" characters, e.g "1"
    FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << oName.c_str() << 1 ;
    return 0;
}
```

This should work.

EDITED: you can put numbers in your 'string' variable as long as you begin with a letter (e.g. "a1"), it works too.

Comment: Thank you so much, however this still doesn't help much because I'd like to enumerate tags using number represents as a strings,  I can't enumerate straight forward using letters.

Comment: @TripleS It seems that only the first character is checked and has to be a letter. This is, you can put a prefix in your variable to make it work, look at my edited answer ;)

Comment: Thank you so much ... already implemented it in alphabetic order :)